# Alert ViewController with Activity Loader Getting Warning and not Dismissing Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertviewcontroller

My scenario, I am trying to create Loader within `AlertViewController`. Here, I am getting below warnings and not allowing to dismiss after two trials. I am using below function in a common class and reusing in multiple viewController.

My Code

```
    // MARK: Common AlertView
        extension UIViewController {

            func loadinHubShow() {

                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
                    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
                    loadingIndicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray
                    loadingIndicator.startAnimating();
                    alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
                    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

                func loadinHubDismiss() {
                    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                }
        }
```

Other ViewController

```
    func dataJson() {

 // Start Loading
    self.loadinHubShow()

// after process done
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.loadinHubDismiss()
    }
}
```

My Warning

> Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller
>    while a presentation or dismiss
>   is in progress!

Comment: the `loadingHubDismiss` what is dismissing ? It doesn't seem to dismiss the alert, It sounds like you're trying to dismiss the controller while presenting the alert

Comment: I am trying to dismiss UIAlertController @Andrew21111

Comment: To dismiss an alert you should call the dismiss function on the alert. Your dismiss function is not related to the alert.
`alert.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)`

Comment: Yes I understand. please provide some code @Andrew21111

Comment: If you ask for code, you should show how and where you use these functions

Comment: I updated my question. Please check it @Andrew21111

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193837/discussion-between-jackios-and-andrew21111).

Comment: show how you use it and where

Comment: do you navigate to any other vc when you dismiss the alert ?

Comment: what the present ??? show full code

Comment: @Sh_Khan Sorry nothing to show full code. just I am using extension and calling it from many view controller. Within extension I used alert show and dismiss.

Comment: inside `dataJson` you navigate to another vc with present/segue after process finishes  ??????

Comment: No. inside within Dispatch I am doing loader dismiss calling function @Sh_Khan

Comment: what is the process ???

Comment: you load the json from local bundle or from an api call ?

Comment: Thanks. Thank you for your awesome quick help @Sh_Khan

Comment: @jackios i clarified it in an answer with a fix if you still need to show the alert in that case

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you're using this functions as `UIViewController` extension.

One way to achieve you're result is to get a reference to the alert you're using.

> ***NOTE:*** If you use `dismiss` function as you did, you're trying to dismiss the viewController, not the alert, that's why you're getting that warning.

Try to change your extension function this way:

1) `loadinHubShow` will return a `reference` to the `alert`

```
      func loadinHubShow() -> UIAlertController {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
            loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            loadingIndicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray
            loadingIndicator.startAnimating();
            alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)

            return alert
            //You don't have to present the alert here
            //present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

2) `loadinHubDismiss` will remove that `alert`:

```
         func loadinHubDismiss(alert: UIAlertController) {
            alert.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
```

In order to use these function, let's assume you have your `ViewController`:

```
            class ViewController: UIViewController{

              var myAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController()

               override func viewDidLoad(...){
                  myAlert = self.loadinHubShow()
                  //now you can present or dismiss the alert wherever you want
                  //for example:
                  self.present(myAlert,animated: false, completion: nil)

                  //when you want dismiss the alert, just call:
                  self. loadinHubDismiss(alert: myAlert)
               }



            }
```

***EDIT***

to dismiss the `alert`, as suggested, try:

```
   DispatchQueue.main.async{
        loadinHubDismiss(alert: myAlert)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to that you do a synchronous json parsing process which causes

```
  func dataJson() { 
      self.loadinHubShow()

   // after process done
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.loadinHubDismiss()
    }
 }
```

the alert to dismiss before it's done showing hence the warning , so either completely remove the alert waiting or use dispatchAfter

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
   self.loadinHubDismiss()
}
```